# Cookie is not seeing token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The cookie name token is shown in my application tab in chrome, but when I run check to get the token, it's returning not found. This is the code.

```
const token = Cookies.get("token")
token ? console.log("cookie found") : console.log("no cookie found")
```

This is my token in my application tab in chrome.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypy9m.png)

This is what my console returns.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8qqP.png)

Comment: Relevant here put errors IN the question not just links to pictures of them. ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/125981

Comment: The `HttpOnly` flag means that it should not be accessible via JavaScript and will only be sent by the browser with http requests.